# What are the host names of Microsoft's Diagnostic Collection servers?

Tags: windows, dns, privacy

I'd like to point them to localhost in my hosts file.

Specifically, the list should cover all servers utilized by:

- Required Diagnostic Data
- Optional Diagnostics Data
- Windows Feedback
- Edge Diagnostic Data
- Office Diagnostic Data
- Visual Studio, VS Code diagnostics, if there are any
- Any other ubiquitous MS product data mining recipients.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Any list we could provide you has the potential of being changed at any point in time.  You should write a PowerShell script that generates the changes to the hosts file automatically for you for the domains you wish to block.  Of course the domains could change at any time, but only you, know what you want to block.

Comment: The server names are surely stored on disk somewhere, be it registry, config files, or whatnot. I'm happy enough to write a script to update hosts upon change detection.

Comment: IIRC, vortex.data.microsoft.com is a VS dump site. It's already in my C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file as 127.0.0.1 vortex.data.microsoft.com. I think I tracked it down using Fiddler.

Comment: @posit - I wouldn't expect a list.  I would expect the binary or executable to handle it, and as updates to either happens, the list would be updated.  The only thing static would be the domains assosicated with Windows Update.

Comment: I would think it highly unlikely that MS hard-codes host names into executables for any of their products. Executables typically store variables in local or user config files, or the Registry, the mother of all config files. So I do expect to compile a list of where to find them, even if it takes some effort. The effort will be much less than trolling around in 1000 UI's looking for switches. It will cover for things for which there are no switches as well. Besides, I'm sure Windows Update updates its own host names on occasion.

Comment: At one time VS ApplicationInsights, Browser Link had some javascript "bugs". It was happily chatting away with these every time I ran a web app debugging session:  dc.services.visualstudio.com, rt.services.visualstudio.com. They earned their very own lines in my hosts file.

Comment: OK, I will grant you that MS hard-codes some DNS resolution to ignore the hosts file with their dnsapi.dll library as I learned at https://hardforum.com/threads/how-to-edit-dnsapi-dll-in-windows-10-to-remove-hard-coded-telemetry-domains.2012159/. It seems to mostly apply to Windows Update, which isn't in the request list.

There is also a program called Spybot that claims to know or can discover the server names. However, I hear they want to add > 15,000 entries into one's hosts file. Not cool. What would be cool is if they published their list so I could truncate it for the limited purpose.

Comment: Isn't it possible to figure this out using something like TCPview? NVM, see Fiddler can do that.

Comment: @Joep - I'm hoping someone has already done the work! It's endless hours. E.g., Spybot has, and then keeps an up-to-date list somewhere. Perhaps the easiest route is to install a low-level SOCKS proxy with logging. Wireshark, Acrylic, et. al.

Answer (score 0):

Not a definitive compilation, but a placeholder and start. I'll try to update as contributions are made.

```
## Windows Diagnostic Data Collection Servers


## Visual Studio Data Collection Servers
127.0.0.1   vortex.data.microsoft.com

## VisualStudio ApplicationInsights, Browser link bugs
127.0.0.1 dc.services.visualstudio.com
127.0.0.1 rt.services.visualstudio.com

## Office Desktop Apps, Diagnostics - perhaps ignore if using Office365
127.0.0.1  ecs.office.com
```

On a separate note:

```
## Mozilla Data Collection Servers
127.0.0.1   ostats.mozilla.com
127.0.0.1   sostats.mozilla.com
127.0.0.1   metrics.mozilla.com
127.0.0.1   hardware.metrics.mozilla.com
127.0.0.1   incoming.telemetry.mozilla.org
127.0.0.1   crash-stats.mozilla.com
127.0.0.1   experiments.mozilla.org
127.0.0.1   getpocket.cdn.mozilla.net
127.0.0.1   qsurvey.mozilla.com
127.0.0.1   telemetry.mozilla.org
127.0.0.1   telemetry-experiment.cdn.mozilla.net
127.0.0.1   detectportal.firefox.com

## Google Servers
127.0.0.1   www.googletagemanager.com
127.0.0.1   www.googleadmanager.com
127.0.0.1   www.google-analytics.com

## Google downloads / Android Studio, et.al.
127.0.0.1   redirector.gvt1.com

## Miscellaneous Servers
127.0.0.1   amazon-adsystem.com
127.0.0.1   c.amazon-adsystem.com
```